# app not seen in "choose an app to run" dropdown menu xcode run project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, simulator

app not seen in "choose an app to run" dropdown menu xcode run project

This is for ObjC/Swift project on simulator run.

DerivedData, Logs and Support folders are deleted from Xcode

Comment: Are you by any chance having workspace but opening .pbxproj?

Comment: Also is it a native or any hybrid or react-native?

Comment: thanks, the problem was solved upon clearing DerivedData folder in XCode and restarting, cleaning and build.

Answer (score 1):

I got a new MacBook and downloaded the current Xcode version 14.1. For some strange reason an app named DanceOff that I had been using for yrs on my previous MacBook with Xcode 12.4 was no longer able to run on my new MacBook. It turns out the scheme was missing (not sure why). To fix it:

1- At the top of your Xcode project, click the top where the red arrow is pointing in the picture.

**Notice in the dropdown there are only 2 things showing for *RichNotifications...***

2- Click Manage Schemes

[image]

3. When the popup window appears scroll to the bottom, notice there **isn't** a check next to *danceoff* (this is my main target). This is what caused my problem.

[image]

I had to **check it**, then selected `Close`.

4. Go back to step 1 again, but this time it will appear in the drop down

[image]

5. I just scrolled to *danceoff* and clicked on it

[image]

Now my app runs fine.